# theme_hook_suggestions in Drupal 7 // Can't get my theme to use my suggestion

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

### General description

I am adding values to `$variables['theme_hook_suggestions']` inside of a theme preprocess function, and yet my theme is not taking the suggestion. I am doing a healthy dose of full cache clearing, so caching is not the problem.

I would like my theme to choose my suggestion, but no matter what I try, it doesn't work.

The above is an abstract version of my problem, a solution to which will probably be useful to most people. A detailed description of my specific setup follows, as well a more specific statement of my problem, and my attempted "solution" (which doesn't work).

Any help you can give me would be tremendous, and very much appreciated. Thank you!

### Setup

In my `template.php` file, I have the following code:

```php
function MYTHEME_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) {  
  $variables['profile'] = array(
    'top_section' => array(
      '#theme'  => 'profile_section',
      '#type' => 'top_section',
      'profile_section' => /* [several renderable elements] */,
    ),
    'bottom_section' => array(
      '#theme'  => 'profile_section',
      '#type' => 'bottom_section',
      'profile_section' => /* [several renderable elements] */,
    ),
  );
}
```

So, in essence, the `MYTHEME_preprocess_user_profile()` function creates several profile sections, assigned to `$variables['profile']`.

I then set up a `user-profile.tpl.php` template file in my theme. Since I am working with a Zen sub-theme, the file goes in my "templates" directory within my theme directory. It looks like this:

```php
<h1 class="title">user-profile.tpl.php</h1>
<?php foreach(element_children($profile) as $section) {
  print render($profile[$section]);  
}
?>
```

I then set up a MYTHEME_theme() function as follows:

```php
function MYTHEME_theme($existing, $type, $theme, $path) {
  return array(
    'profile_section' => array(
      'render element' => 'profile_section',
      'template' => 'templates/profile-section',
    ),
  );
}
```

And, lastly, I set up a `profile-section.tpl.php` file in my templates directory, as follows:

```
<h2>profile-section.tpl.php</h2>
<p>Theming the profile section <strong><php print $profile_section['#type'] ?></strong> with the <strong>standard</strong> profile section template.</strong></p>
```

With this in place, I get all of the desired behavior for what how I want the theme to react to the sections of my user profile, under most circumstances. That is, for each of my profile sections, I can theme it as a "profile_section."

### Problem

I also want the ability to set up template files to handle the theming of specific profile sections, based on new template files I drop into my templates directory. So, specific to this example, while I want `profile-section.tpl.php` to handle most profile sections, I also want the ability to drop in a `profile-section--top-section.tpl.php` file, clear the cache, and have the theme use that file for the "top_section" profile section.

### My "solution", which does not work

I have read that my problem can be solved by using theme_hook_suggestions, within the appropriate theme preprocess function. So, in my case, I wrote a `MYTHEME_preprocess_profile_section()` function, as follows:

```php
function MYTHEME_preprocess_profile_section(&$variables) {
  $variables['theme_hook_suggestions'][] = 'profile_section__' . $variables['profile_section']['#type'];
}
```

I then wrote a `profile-section--top-section.tpl.php` file as follows:

```
<h2>profile-section--top-section.tpl.php</h2>
<p>Theming the profile section <strong><php print $profile_section['#type'] ?></strong> with the <strong>top-sectoin</strong> profile section template.</strong></p>
```

That completes my setup. I refresh the cache, but...

The theme still chooses the `profile-section.tpl.php` template for my top_section profile_section, rather than the more specific `profile_section__top_section.tpl.php` template I wrote.

What do I need to do from here, or what should I change, to make this setup take my theme suggestion from `MYTHEME_preprocess_profile_section()`?

Comment: Is the file called profile_section__top_section.tpl.php, or is it called profile-section--top-section.tpl.php? I sometimes find that Drupal converts the _ to - for use in filenames. Try changing the name of the file, and see if that helps.